# Where to get average US profit by industry?

Tags: business

I'm looking more for average profits of small businesses per year, which are 99.7% of the US businesses, as defined by the SBA. The [BLS.GOV](http://www.bls.gov/data/%20BLS.GOV) website has a lot of data by industry, but I couldn't find any data on average profits by industry. Hopefully I'd like to see profits going back to 2007. I'm a Perl programmer so I plan to read this raw data and analyze it myself by industry.

Thank you.

Comment: Try looking for "value added by industry site:bea.gov".

Comment: Definition from http://www.bea.gov/faq/index.cfm?faq_id=184.  Ok, so if a product's materials cost me $10, labor costs me $20, and I pay another company to do labor of $20, and I sell a product for $80, the GDP for that transaction is: 80-10-20-20, or $30. Is that right? That might get me in the ballpark.Is GDP for an industry the same thing as profit for an industry?

Comment: It's a rough measure that must be adjusted for taxes, etc. Another source for profits is business surveys (censuses) on data.gov.

Comment: http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~adamodar/New_Home_Page/datafile/margin.html looks interested my, but not quite what I believe you want.